# how to uninstall SUSE linux

Tags: uninstall

i am assuming the procedure is similar to ubuntus so someone 
help me uninstall SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 and installing windows 7.currently my notebook is running the linux only and am not interested in recovering any data

Comment: Questions on Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate to Ubuntu, within the scope defined in the faq. If you got problems with this you should ask it on a windows forum if you want windows installed.

Comment: If you are installing Windows, just install windows and use the entire drive.

Answer (score 3):

1. Take your windows 7 installation CD.
2. Insert it into your CD drive.
3. Reboot your computer.
4. Tell your BIOS to boot from the CD.
5. Follow the instructions.